# its possible make a stream reader that Read 5 lines at a time instead of one?

Tags: c#

I use a `StreamReader` but it only reads one line at a time.

My question is: Is it possible to change this behaviour so I can read more than one? For example: **5** lines at a time?

```
using System;
using System.IO; 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class example 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        var path = "pruebastream.txt";
        var path2 = "pruebastream2.txt";
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(path2))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var text = ProcessLine(line);
                outputFile.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }
    }
    static string ProcessLine(string text)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you still need to process a line at time there is no much to gain in reading 5 lines together. Can you explain why you need to read 5 lines at time?

Comment: yes , generally i used a regex command but this command works whith more than one line ( its a comand for sum elements of table )

Comment: You can write an extension for the StreamReader that loads 5 lines in an array and returns it (but you still need to check if you have read less that 5 lines in case your file has a number of lines not exactly a  multiple of 5)

Comment: How big is the file? If its not that big, you should just read the entire thing into memory with File.ReadAllLines. Only time you really need to use StreamReader is when your file is huge. If your file is say <= 1GB, you'd be fine reading it all in for a console app assuming you are compiling to x64.

Comment: Also, there is no point in using a BufferedStream where you used it.

Comment: if you want to call the method every 5 lines, why don't you use a counter? then `if (i % 5 == 0) // call the method.` A different approach is reading and storing all the lines, and the processing 5 per time. The latter approach will be a memory problem if the file is huge.

Comment: ok thanks peval27, i will try with this

Comment: SledgeHammer my command its a little complex , my file is 50 mb , I have tried the same command with 25 mb and it works fine
But when it exceeds this amount it starts to linger a lot

Comment: @jhonny625 50MB is nothing. Read it in all at once using File.ReadAllLines(), that will give you an array of lines. If you need to split it into batches, you can use Linq Take on the array.

Comment: the problem is that if i split in lines the regex command cant use the next line

Comment: the other problem is true my file is 50mb but i use the regex command for consult aprox 7 lines  then the command is consult 50mb x 7 lines

Comment: 350 mb or more this increment the complexity , i dont sure if the method that you describe  would works

Comment: if you could explain this with example I would be so grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get downvoted a bit, but easier approach can be to just use 5 `.ReadLine`:

```
using (var sr = File.OpenText("1.txt"))
using (var sw = File.CreateText("2.txt"))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var s = sr.ReadLine() + "\r\n" + sr.ReadLine() + "\r\n" + 
            sr.ReadLine() + "\r\n" + sr.ReadLine() + "\r\n" + sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, use counter variable if you don't want the extra newline characters after the last few lines.

Comment: Yeah, why shouldn't it? The code will crash 99% of the time since you aren't checking sr.EndOfStream for each ReadLine.

Comment: @SledgeHammer that is one of the reasons .. assuming things without testing (which I often do too). `.ReadLine()` just returns null no matter how many times it is called. I tested the code before posting.

Comment: SledgeHammer  I'm a bit confused about this , the problem if that i split in  lines the command cant use more than one line